# How To Disable vBulletin Forum?

Tags: forum, vbulletin

How to disable vBulletin Forum from **ADMIN CP > PLUGINS & PRODUCTS >MANAGE PRODUCTS** ?
I know it's quite tough and got a link too for this but I was unsure ... if possible it would be good.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vBulletin 4.x: AdminCP > Settings > Options > Turn vBulletin On or Off

vBulletin 3.x: vBulletin Options > vBulletin Options > Turn vBulletin On or Off

You can't disable the actual vBulletin product from the products area.